# How to do a price comparison for a product in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following data:

```
product_id       store           price
1                itunes          8.99
1                google          9.99
1                amazon          10.00
2                itunes          10.00
2                google          4.99
```

How would I do a query where I get all `product_id`s where the price is higher on iTunes than it is in Google. In the above example, it would be:

```
product_id      itunes      google
2               10.00       4.99
```

So far I have an aggregation query to do this, but am getting caught up in the price comparison part:

```
SELECT 
  product_id, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(case when platform_type_id='itunes' then price end) itunes,
  GROUP_CONCAT(case when platform_type_id='google' then price end) google
 FROM 
  table GROUP BY product_id
```

The query is incomplete, but was the direction I was going. What would be the correct way to do this?

Comment: Change direction, and see about JOINs!

Comment: And why don't you want product 1?

Comment: @Strawberry sorry yes that was a typo, edited above. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @David542 Because your headline makes it not clear to me: Do you want an explicit MySQL solution? For Postgres this could be: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/0979a/13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a comparison in `having`.

```
SELECT 
  product_id, 
  MAX(CASE WHEN store='itunes' THEN PRICE END) as itunes,
  MAX(CASE WHEN store='google' THEN PRICE END) as google
FROM table 
GROUP BY product_id
HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN store='itunes' THEN PRICE END) >  MAX(CASE WHEN store='google' THEN PRICE END)
```

EDIT:

You can simplify the `HAVING` clause to:

```
HAVING itunes > google
```

Answer (score 3):

Another possible solution would use an `INNER JOIN` connecting each iTunes product with the corresponding Google product where Google is cheaper.

```
SELECT ti.product_id,
       ti.price itunes,
       tg.price google
       FROM elbat ti
            INNER JOIN elbat tg
                       ON tg.product_id = ti.product_id
                          AND tg.price < ti.price
       WHERE ti.store = 'itunes'
             AND tg.store = 'google';
```

Comment: oh that's a very straightforward solution, I like this one a lot -- much cleaner than the route I was going.

Answer (score -1):

In Postgres though:

```
with itunes as (select productid, price from table_ where store='itunes'),
google as (select productid,price table_ where store='google')

Select itunes.productid, itunes.price as "price", google as "price"
From itunes,google
Where itunes.price>google.price
```

Comment: I didn't downvote but you cross join every product on Google with every product on iTunes and don't connect corresponding products. Your query retrieves a product, that is offered by iTunes, if **any** product is cheaper than it on Google, not necessarily the same product. E.g it will return product 1 even if it's more expensive on Google because product 2 is cheaper than product 1 on Google.

Comment: Oh, okey noted; I undestand now